# How to optimize speed in spatial thinning in r

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal, terra

### The problem

I am embarking on a project were I will need to build more or less
30,000 species distribution models (SDM), and I have been testing several ideas. Right now my bottleneck is to speed up the spatial thinning (for species with a lot of presences), which I had been doing with the SpThin package.

My idea is that since SpThin is made with the idea that you will get the most presences this is not needed for species where you have a ton of presences.

So I set up to try what is out there, and also try to come up with new
ideas myself:

So let's load the packages

```r
library(terra)
library(spThin)
library(enmSdmX)
library(microbenchmark)
```

### Example data:

Here is an example dataset for speed sake, at the end I will show a more complex dataset:

```r
example <- structure(list(x = c(1.5, 2.5, 2, 5.5, 7.5), y = c(1.5, 2.5, 
                                                              2, 5.5, 7.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

example$ID <- 1:nrow(example)
example$Sp <- "A"
example_spat <- vect(example, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", geom = c("x", "y"))
```

So here you can see the points I created:

[image]

When I make a buffer of 80 kms then I can see an overlap:

[image]

So now let's use microbenchmark to see what is out there:

```r
Test <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  A = enmSdmX::geoThin(example_spat, minDist = 80000), 
  B = enmSdmX::geoThin(example_spat, minDist = 80000, random = T),
  c = spThin::thin(loc.data = as.data.frame(example), thin.par = 80, reps = 1, write.files = F, write.log.file = F, lat.col = "x", long.col = "y", spec.col = "Sp"),
  times = 100)
```

As you can see below:

[image]

It seems that enmSdmX random is the fastest.

However as you will see below this changes with bigger datasets

### What happens with more data:

I tested this with a package I am developing
[here](https://github.com/Sustainscapes/SDMWorkflows/)

If you want to go there you can install it like this:

```r
remotes::install_github("Sustainscapes/SDMWorkflows")
```

```r
library(SDMWorkflows)

Presences <- SDMWorkflows::GetOccs(Species = c("Abies concolor"), WriteFile = FALSE, limit = 2000)
Cleaned <- clean_presences(Presences[[1]])

spat_vect <- terra::vect(as.data.frame(Cleaned), geom=c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

```r
Test <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  A = enmSdmX::geoThin(spat_vect, minDist = 10000), 
  B = enmSdmX::geoThin(spat_vect, minDist = 10000, random = T),
  c = spThin::thin(loc.data = as.data.frame(example), thin.par = 10, reps = 1, write.files = F, write.log.file = F, lat.col = "x", long.col = "y", spec.col = "Sp"),
  times = 20)
```

As you can see below:

[image]

Now it is almost inverted, where SpThin is the fastest, now this are awful news for me, since I am having a bottleneck with SpThin in species with large datasets. I have tried to build 2 or 3 new function but so far non of the are faster.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question. There are many different ways in which you could remove points but you do not specify what your requirements are. What is your expected output given an input data set. Approximate or exact? How adaptive to data set characteristics should it be? You show overlapping buffers, but which points are removed? Perhaps `dismo::gridSample` works for you?  Right now you show speed of some functions that are not described, it is not clear what your question really is.